# Access facebook friends public posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I want to access my facebook friends public posts for some sentiment analysis stuff. Can anyone help in knowing how it can be done using GraphAPI ?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t access data of friends anymore. All friend permissions are gone:

> All friends_* permissions have been removed.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the removal of the `friends_*` permissions, you can no longer get the whole friend list anymore, but only those who are also using your app.

So, what you want to achieve is unfortunately pretty much impossible.